# need assistance on constructing sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have three tables like follows:

this one table : `m_application_resources`

```
 resourceid resource_name   menu_group_id   menu_name   creation_date   last_created_by updation_date   last_updated_by
```

and the second table : `m_roles`

```
roleid  rolename    description creation_date   last_created_by updation_date   last_updated_by
```

and the third table is : `m_access_matrix`

```
accessid    resourceid  roleid  creation_date   last_created_by updation_date   last_updated_by
```

Relationship for the table is : resourceid and roleid

and this my query

```
select  am.accessid, ar.resource_name,rls.rolename
from m_application_resources ar, m_roles rls,m_access_matrix am 
where ar.resourceid=am.resourceid
```

this returns the following :

```
ccessid resource_name   rolename
1   DepartmentAction    Admin
1   DepartmentAction    Client
1   DepartmentAction    Doctors
2   PositionsAction     Admin
2   PositionsAction     Client
2   PositionsAction     Doctor
```

the result is wrong and i don't know how to go about.

Ex : DepartmentAction should come only once and the role name should be any one.

Sqlfiddle[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fca3/3)

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a condition on `role_id`:

```
select  am.accessid, ar.resource_name,rls.rolename
from m_application_resources ar, m_roles rls,m_access_matrix am 
where ar.resourceid=am.resourceid AND am.roleid = rls.roleid
```

I would convert the query to ANSI SQL syntax for joins for better clarity:

```
SELECT am.accessid, ar.resource_name,rls.rolename
FROM m_application_resources ar
JOIN m_access_matrix am ON ar.resourceid=am.resourceid
JOIN m_roles rls ON am.roleid = rls.roleid
```

Comment: Great point converting to ANSI syntax.  Please do take that advice and use proper formatting in your code.

Comment: the query gives empty result set but i have some values

Comment: @Anto Very interesting... Could you create a "sandbox" on [www.sqlfiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with the sample data, and post a link?

Comment: thanks i shall give you the tables, Please have a look at update

Comment: Hi are you there, need help on this very badly, thanks and sorry for disturbing you

Comment: @Anto: Please take a closer look at the example you've posted. All `m_access_matrix` rows reference the `roleid` of 1, but `m_roles` doesn't have a row by that `roleid`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be best to explicitly join the tables in your query.  I'm not 100% sure I understand your tables, but this should work:

```
SELECT am.accessid, ar.resource_name, rls.rolename
FROM (m_application_resources ar INNER JOIN m_access_matrix am 
ON ar.resourceid = am.resourceid) INNER JOIN mroles rls ON am.roleid = rls.roleid
```

Comment: the query gives empty result set but i have some values